# Sinon spy method that is called in backbone view initialize

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I execute a method in the Backbone's View initialize method.

```
initialize : function(options) {
      this.myMethod();
   }
```

I am trying to spy on this method using sinon like:

```
this.spyMyMethod = sinon.spy(this.view, "myMethod");
```

end then

```
it('should call my method', function(){
  expect(this.spyMyMethod).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
});
```

but the test fails...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are spying on the method too late.

Wherever you are assigning `this.view` I assume it is from a call like `new Views.SomeView()`. It is that `new` call that will make the `initialize` function be executed.

**Update**

I don't really recommend doing this because it is pretty messy, but you can possibly do something like the following: (I don't know sinon but this is how you would do it with the base jasmine spy objects)

```
it('should call my method', function(){
  var dummyView = new Views.SomeView();
  spyOn(dummyView, "myMethod");
  spyOn(Views, "SomeView").andCallFake(function () {
    dummyView.initialize();
    return dummyView;
  });
  new Views.SomeView();
  expect(dummyView.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Another Possiblilty**

Looks like it might be possible to override that method with a spy like below. If that works, it is probably the cleanest way to do this.

```
it('should call my method', function(){
  spyOn(Views.SomeView.prototype, "myMethod");
  new Views.SomeView();
  expect(Views.SomeView.prototype.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to spy earlier? Maybe spy the prototype of Backbone.View?

Comment: Maybe. Try something like what I added. I don't really recommend doing this though. It is starting to get kind of nasty and may not really give you that much in the way of testing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return a **new** instance of your view for the initialize method to be called.

I'm not sure if this.view = new View(); already however

Comment: Hello, I create a new instance with new